# Запись массива товаров в сессию

Tags: php

Есть пост обработчик который принимает  $id товара.
Как сделать массив в который будут добавляться товары в конец, а потом массив в сессию

Comment: а вы что то пробовали сделать ? есть какой-то свой код ?

Comment: Для добавления в конец `array_push()`, А потос просто `$_SESSION['products'] = $array;`

Comment: Я пробовал, но ничего не получалось, удалил

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы добавить один элемент в конец массива, используется оператор `[]`.
При этом "потом" ничего добавлять не надо, можно сразу записать в сессию

То есть в простейшем случае, когда предаётся просто id товара, пишем

```
$_SESSION['products'][] = $id;
```

Но в реальности в корзину пишут не только ид товара, но и количество. В этом случае код будет чуть сложнее

```
$_SESSION['products'][$id] = $quantity;
```

Добавить же массив товаров очень просто. Как и любой массив, просто обрабатываем его в цикле

```
foreach ($_POST['cart'] as $id => $quantity) {
    $_SESSION['products'][$id] = $quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Постарался всю логику по шагам показать:

```
<?php 

/* Проверяете есть ли POST ID */
if(isset($_POST['id'])){

/* "Открываете сессию"  */
session_start();
$data = array();

$data = $_SESSION['prID'];

/* Проверяете, нет ли уже данного ID  */
if(!in_array($_POST['id'],$data)){

/* Добавляете ID в массив  */
array_push($data,$_POST['id']);

/* Добавляете массив в сессию */
$_SESSION['prID'] = $data;
}


}
?>
```

P.S конечно можно укоротить шаги.. )

Answer (score 0):

Компонент php для корзины:

```
<?php
class Cart
{
    public static function addProduct($id,$count = 1)
    {
        $id = intval($id);
        $productsInCart = array();
        if (isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
            $productsInCart = $_SESSION['products'];
        }
        if (array_key_exists($id, $productsInCart)){
            $productsInCart[$id] += $count;
        } else {
            $productsInCart[$id] = $count;
        }
        $_SESSION['products'] = $productsInCart;

        return self::countItems();
    }
    public static function countItems()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $id => $quantity) {
                $count = $count + $quantity;
            }
            return $count;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public static function getProducts()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
            return $_SESSION['products'];
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static function clear()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['products']);
        }
    }
    public static function deleteProduct($id)
    {
        $productsInCart = self::getProducts();
        unset($productsInCart[$id]);
        $_SESSION['products'] = $productsInCart;
    }

}
```